# Constant current - what is the difference between loads

Tags: power-supply, current-source

This question is more about what terms I need to be using in my search, as I haven't had much luck yet with my searches.

With a constant current power supply, where voltage is set to 12 V and current limit is set to 500mA, if I connect an LED lamp that uses about 600mA, as expected I see it reach the maximum current with a small voltage drop.

If I connect a different load, like a dummy load tester, whenever I turn the potentiometer just above the threshold value, the voltage drops to under 1 V, even though I've set the current to barely above the limit.

I am trying to find out what is behind this difference. Why does a LED or Battery behave differently with a CC source? I feel I have a missing piece here, so would appreciate some direction.

Comment: Was the dummy load in constant current mode? Or constant resistance mode? Constant power mode?

Comment: That im not sure. Couldnt find any setting for constant current mode. https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0108/8313/7600/products/4_19c0eb44-b503-456b-ac7a-1c9f10ade81f_900x.jpg?v=1545037389 this is the manual for the device. What would "constant current mode" mean in terms of the circuit. I'm not sure I understand that.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is how the load draws current.

A 12V 600mA LED would ideally draw 600mA only when it has 12V.
It will draw less current when it has less voltage, for example it might draw 500mA at 11V.

So for example if you power it with a power supply that is set to 12V constant voltage with 500mA current limit, the LED would initially try to draw 600mA because of the 12V provided, but the power supply hits the current limit and it will drop the output voltage until the current draw is 500mA and the power supply output voltage ends up being 11V.

The dummy load is most likely using constant current mode. If you set it to 400mA, and connect it to 12V power supply with 500mA current limit, the dummy load will start drawing 400mA, and since the power supply has no problems providing 12V at 400mA, the voltage will stay at 12V.

When you start cranking up the current on the dummy load, you can hit up to 500mA, because the power supply is set to provide only 500mA, and voltage is still 12V. When you set the dummy load to 501mA, it will try to always draw 501mA, no matter what. The power supply has now hit the 500mA limit, and will start dropping the output voltage to keep the output current limited to 500mA. But the dummy load would still like to keep drawing 501mA regardless of the voltage, so even if the power supply output drops to 1V, the dummy load would still try to draw 501mA and power supply must continue dropping voltage in order to try limit the current, and the result is that power supply output voltage will be quite low near 0V and much below 501mA flows as there is not enough voltage in the system for the dummy load to draw 501mA at so low voltage.

Another example with e.g. small 12V motorcycle battery. Assume it empty at 8V, and needs charging to 12V, and it must be charged at maximum current of 500mA so it does not explode. So you set the power supply to 12V voltage, and current limit to 500mA. As current is limited to 500mA, the power supply voltage is also 8V. When battery charges at 500mA constant current, voltage rises up to 12V, and then power supply gets limited to 12V. The battery won't draw 500mA any more, but current drops more and more when battery gets more full. If left on indefinitely, the battery would reach 12V too, and since both battery and supply are at 12V, and current would drop to 0.

Comment: Ok, thanks now we are getting somewhere! You helped me verbalize the question: what allows the LED to make that "adjustment"

Comment: I think I was confused by the behaviour of this dummy load. If I connect any resistor I see that it behaves as expected. I guess I was seeing constant current load + constant current source giving me that result.

Answer (score 1):

### Initial Response

When you set up a power supply with limits for both current and voltage, the power supply ideally operates within a rectangle of allowed behavior.

Below, I'm including a diagram that illustrates four different loads where I use your power supply limit settings of \$500\:\text{mA}\$ and \$12\:\text{V}\$. Within the diagram, you should see a brown rectangle that encloses the power supply's allowed behavior. The background of that area is marked in a white color, too.

[image]

I've included an LED (turquoise color), two resistors (one is dark blue and the other is red), and a two-BJT active load designed for about \$500\:\text{mA}\$ (the bright green color.)

The red \$39\:\Omega\$ resistor won't permit \$500\:\text{mA}\$ when the power supply is limited to \$12\:\text{V}\$. So in this case the power supply will show \$12\:\text{V}\$, along with about \$300\:\text{mA}\$. The power supply is relying on its voltage limit, with the required current well within its current limit.

The dark blue \$16\:\Omega\$ resistor will show about \$8\:\text{V}\$ on your power supply, along with \$500\:\text{mA}\$. In this case, the power supply is relying on its current limit and had to limit the voltage in order to meet that current limit setting.

The LED rapidly reaches the power supply's current limit, so it will show about \$3.3\:\text{V}\$ on your power supply, along with \$500\:\text{mA}\$. (This particular LED is designed for \$400\:\text{mA}\$ and so it will probably be fine -- assuming the added thermal issues are dealt with.)

The active current load using two BJTs and some resistors has a voltage overhead requirement of over \$4\:\text{V}\$. Once it reaches that voltage level, it tends to permit its set current of about \$500\:\text{mA}\$. In this case, the power supply's current limit is reached when the voltage is about \$7\:\text{V}\$, so that would also be what the power supply shows on its display in this case.

But if the active current load had been set lower, for say \$350\:\text{mA}\$, then the power supply's current limit would not be exceeded and a full \$12\:\text{V}\$ would appear across the active current limit circuit and the current would show whatever the load allowed at that voltage (hopefully close to \$350\:\text{mA}\$.)

(Note that the active load behaves a lot more like a resistor below \$4\:\text{V}\$, except as the supply voltage nears \$500\:\text{mV}\$ where the behavior changes, again.)

Hopefully, that should help make things a little clearer using a picture.

### Later Response: Low Voltage with Constant Current

In the following chart, I used a similar 2-BJT constant current circuit, but changed the x-y axis arrangement.

[image]

When examining the above chart, imagine that the power supply is set for a current limit of \$10\:\text{mA}\$ and a voltage limit of \$12\:\text{V}\$. Now look at the chart and I think you will see that the power supply voltage will be quite low, about \$2\:\text{V}\$, despite the fact that the power supply's *set* voltage limit is much higher. This is simply because the power supply's *set* current limit is \$10\:\text{mA}\$ and this is achieved at a relatively low voltage. So it applies first and limits the output voltage applied to the load.

Nearby current limit settings won't change the voltage much. The curve is fairly flat around that point. And it won't matter if you raise the power supply's *set* voltage to \$20\:\text{V}\$ or \$30\:\text{V}\$. The current limit will still take over.

Comment: Thank you jonk. This is helpful to me, but I think I am still missing something. I get why resistors, batteries, etc. work as expected and drop their voltage proportionally ot the current they are trying to draw. What I don't get is why a "constant current load" like my dummy load tester causes an immediate drop to 0. Another answerer said it was because it keeps trying to pull more and more current. I am just trying to understand the mechanism "under the hood" for this type of load and what causes the drop to 0

Comment: @LioreShai It would probably be easier to see if I changed the \$y\$-axis to voltage and the \$x\$-axis to current. It's nothing magic. I just chose the wrong axis arrangement to make it easier to see. I'll add something when I get a moment.

Comment: @LioreShai I've added a chart at the bottom to help out. Hopefully, anyway.